# navigation Done item not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

in the top view of my view controller (the last table view controller) has an add navigation item. i added a view controller object from the objects library and i ctrl + dragged from the plus button to the view controller. i tried the app and it works fine but i can't go back to the previous controller when i reach the last controller. since the last controller connected (by segue) to the plus button, i can't have a navigation bar on top. so i added one and added an navigation item called it Done. i created an IBAction method in the class that the last controller subclasses which have the following code:

`[self.navigationController popNavigationControllerAnimated:YES];`

However, when i run the app and press the Done button to go back, it doesn't work although i feel like what i did is totally legal.

Comment: What do you mean by "i can't have a navigation bar on top"?

Comment: when i choose the style of the segue to be Model the navigation bar disappears. i tried to add [self.navigationController setNaigdationBarHidden:NO] in viewWillAppear and it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would have made the final view controller segue a Push segue, you'd still have the navigation bar with a back button. It makes sense since you're adding a record that you'd want a modal view.

You can dismiss the current modal view with the following code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Generally, you should use delegation and dismiss it from the presenting view controller. However, I think it's fine to dismiss yourself if you're using storyboards, segues, and ARC.

Comment: Thank you so much! worked like a charm :P but please can you tell me what do you mean to use delegation and dismiss it from the presenting view controller? Thanks again.

Comment: [Using Delegation to Communicate with other Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW9)

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a Bar Button Item and assigned its 'selector' callback?

Comment: nope. i do know how to do that but i wanna try an alternative. can't i add a navigation item and connect it to a method i created ? [Note: i'm using model styles segue and i added my own navigation bar]

Comment: First - You will need to create a bar button item that says 'Done'. Second - You will have to assign to its 'selector' callback, you can assign it to a method you've already created as well